# Как получить массив данных с разных URL с помощью RxJs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Например есть `/api/item/1`, возвращающий `{id: 1, data: "data1"}` и `/api/item/2`, возвращающий `{id: 2, data: "data2"}`, и так далее. Я хочу получить массивом все объекты так, чтобы получить `[{id: 1, data: "data1"}, {id: 2, data: "data2"}]`. Пробовал делать по примеру так:

```js
Observable.from(ids)
.mergeMap(res => this.getItemById(res)) //метод возвращающий Observable
.concatAll()
```

Не получилось, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: а `ids` что такое у вас?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n массив id итемов, для моего примера будет [1,2, ...] , в соответствии с которым происходит запрос. Метод this.getItemById(id) выполняет этот запрос и возвращает Observable<Item>. Я хочу преобразовать эти последовательные запросы к разным URL так, чтобы сразу получить массив результатов. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: [Это](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) не то?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n В этом варианте необходимо вручную перечислять Observable. Я кажется нашел рабочий вариант, добавлю как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сработал такой вариант:

```js
Observable.from(ids)
.map((id: number) => {return this.getItemById(id)})
.mergeAll().toArray();
```

Возможно, можно это решить проще